# what most likely is this Intrinsics method

Tags: android, kotlin, decompiling

I was decompiling some apk and came across this

```
protected ButtonAction(String str) {
    Intrinsics.m27292b(str, "action");
    this.action = str;
}

public final void m23619h(String str) {
    Intrinsics.m27292b(str, "donationGroup");
    this.f14615e.edit().putString("donation_group", str).apply();
}
```

I understand the `Intrinsics` come from:

```
import kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics;
```

My question is what most likely is the `m27292b`?
I know this is kind of abstract but I try to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f14615e` might be `SharedPreferences` ...as `.edit()` and `.apply()` hint for.

while the signature of `Intrinsics.m27292b` matches various methods of [Intrinsics](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/jvm/runtime/kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.java). it could be any method, which would accept two `String` as parameters; it might be asserting `str` not being `null`.

```
public static void checkParameterIsNotNull(Object value, String paramName) {
    if (value == null) {
        throwParameterIsNullException(paramName);
    }
}
```